# Flask Request object in Visual Studio does not contain .method

Tags: python, flask

I am a novice Python/Flask developer and am struggling with something basic.

I am using Visual Studio and have created a Flask project. All the documentation I read refers to the use of request.method etc. however the Request object I load with:

```
from flask import Session, Request, Response
```

Does not provide that and other extensions I need, instead I have access to `.blueprint`, `.endpoint` etc.

Has anyone else come across this issue? How do I get to `request.method`?

This is my first question post so if you need more information then please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that `Request` and `request` are two different things. When I go into the Python shell I can see:

```
>>> from flask import Request
>>> Request
<class 'flask.wrappers.Request'>
>>> from flask import request
>>> request
<LocalProxy unbound>
```

When you receive a request, Flask creates an instance of a subclass of `Request` for you that is bound to `request`, so when you import that you can use all the methods of the instance and class, like `request.args` to get all arguments from the query string. See the documentation at [the flask website](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been reading about it and think I now understand it. Most importantly it seems to be working.